to fetch file link attached to the record in salesforce using PA
I want to fetch a downloadable link of files attached to the employee record in salesforce using Power automate flow but I'm using this link: https://abcd.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/068IR00000UcabCYAR/VersionData to fetch link, is it correct?? it's showing error like : invalid session How to resolve ??
I tried to fetch the file link but it's showing error
